# git -Lost everything before comitting, is there hope for recovery

Tags: git

I tried to add my month old project to git. This was my first real project and git. After creating the repository (git init), I staged them(git add .) and added my .gitignore to ignore all the unnecessary files. This didn't work so I decided to remove all the staged files and try again. I ended up removing everything, I mean EVERYTHING. So nothing was ever committed and the rm option deleted everything. 
What I did notice is the the .git directory is about 130mb which tells me even though I have never committed and cleared the staging area it must still have some sort of copy of my original staged files? Is there any way that I can try and recover?

Comment: What have you done in detail and what is git status telling you?

Comment: Your `.git` directory could contain 130MB simply because you intially cloned the project, this size does not necessarily imply that there are any blobs in there corresponding to your lost work.

Comment: If you did a git add, then you might still have the files there staged for commit. If git status says a bunch of files added are staged for commit, and then there are a bunch of changes not staged for commit, then you still have them.

git commit to commit the add, then git reset --hard to undo the deletion? Copy the folder and try on a backup first!

Comment: Always make a backup before doing anything dangerous if you're not very sure you know what you're doing.  'Tis a bit late to be offering that advice for this scenario, but remember it for the future.  Also, start using `git` on day 1 of your project, not on day 30.  It makes it easier to keep things straight.

Comment: A quick summary of what I did
1.git init
2.git Add . 
3.Add my .gitignore files
4.git --status (Showed all the unwanted files as well)
5.git commit(Without the comment. Tried to se if .gitignore only works with commit /staged. Saw all the unwanted files in commit comment. Cancelled)
6.git -rm (with all the flags)
7.git status (Showed staging area is empty)
8.git add . (Now only showed my .gitignore files, investigate and realize all is lost)
Lesson learned...Very hard way though

Answer (score 9):

If you've `git add`ed files and then unstaged and deleted them you can usually recover your data using `git fsck`.

The key here is that `git add` creates a blob in the git repo for your file, but `git rm` etc do not remove the blob, only the file. The git repo will later delete the old and unused blobs either automatically when you run a command in the future, or when you run `git gc`. But until then the blob is still there it is just "dangling" - meaning nothing references it. You can use this to recover your data.

Problem is that you lose filenames and if the repo has been around for a while you may need to sift through a lot of dangling references.

Here's an example, going from woe to go.

Create a new git repo, create file, add it, remove it, delete it.

```
> git init .
> echo "HELLO WORLD" > hello.txt
> git add hello.txt
> git rm hello.txt
```

Now try to find the old files content

```
> git fsck --full
...
dangling blob 4e3dffe8
...
```

We can now recover it

```
> git show 4e3dffe8
HELLO WORLD
> git show 4e3dffe8 > hello.txt
```

Comment: git fsck --full
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references

Comment: As per my comments on the original question. I assume my last add is why the fsck --full is not showing anything